# How do I detect the page the user came from in vue.js when the page opens in a new tab?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, router

I've got an interesting problem in my vue.js application and I don't know how to solve it.

We've got a "my listings" page that shows a grid of listings that the user created. When they click on one, it takes them to the listing details page. It opens this page in a new browser tab.

What we want to do is add a new component to the top of the page that shows the user the stats on their listing. But we want this component to show up ONLY when they come to the listing details page from the My Listings page. There are other ways of getting to the Listing Details page and we don't want the stats component to show up when they come from these other ways.

I would think this could be handled in the router. I tried seeing if I could detect that the user was coming from the My Listings page from the "from" parameter in the beforeEach(...) method of the router. I did this:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    console.log('from=', from);
    console.log('to=', to);
});
```

When it prints the from parameter, I get this:

```
to= {
fullPath: "/"
hash: ""
matched: []
meta: {}
name: null
params: {}
path: "/"
query: {}
}
```

It contains no information about where it came from. I'm guessing this is because it opens the Listing Details page in a new tab. So I can't use the router to tell where the user came from.

Instead, I resorted to using localStorage:

On the My Listings page:

```
<v-btn :href="`/listings/${listing.listingId}`" target="_blank" @click="saveFromMyListings();">View Listing</v-btn>

...

saveFromMyListings() {
  localStorage.setItem('from-my-listings', true);
},
```

On the Listing Details page:

```
async created () {
    this.fromMyListings = localStorage.getItem('from-my-listings') === 'true';
    localStorage.setItem('from-my-listings', false);
},
```

So long as I set the 'from-my-listings' item in localStorage to false immediately after I use it to determine that the user came from the My Listings page, it works. That way, it is ONLY set if the user comes from the My Listings page, and never set if the user comes from anywhere else.

The problem with this method is that if the user refreshes the page, the stats disappear. Obviously, this is because created() reruns and this time 'from-my-listings' is removed from localStorage. I can fix this by not setting it to false in created() once it's used, but then where do I remove it in such a way that it's guaranteed to be removed no matter how the user leaves the page (entering a new url directly in the browser, closing the browser, computer loses power, etc.)?

Is there some other hook in vue.js besides created() that runs only once (when the user first visits the page) but not on subsequent loads (like refresh)? Is there a way to pass props to a component in the router based on the state of localStorage that won't have to be passed again on refresh? What other solutions might there be to this problem?

Comment: Brodcastchannel to sync multiple tabs from one origin, polyfill with localstorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use query parameters. You'd have to change the links to something like this:

`yourapp.com/listing-detail/333?from=list`

then in the `created` function you can check `window.location.search` for the `from` value